# Simple Nested loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

Simple question regarding nested loops.

```
stocks = {'GE': 6.28, 'XOM': 39.8}
for quote in stocks.values():
    print(quote)

    for symbol in stocks.keys():
        print(symbol)

        print('You have purchased', symbol, 'for', quote)
```

Output:

```
GE
You have purchased GE for 39.8
XOM
You have purchased XOM for 39.8
```

Why does it state that `GE` was purchased at `39.8` and not `6.28`?
I tried to indent and dedent the loop code but to no luck. Please help?

Comment: That is not the full output, which would very clearly show that the values and keys are iterated separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries are not (typically) ordered.

You will need to print in the same order as you traverse:

```
for k, v in stocks.items():
    print(k)
    print('You have purchased', k, 'for', v)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to print the key and value of a dict, then just unpack both in one for loop:

```
for symbol, quote in stocks.items():
    print(symbol)
    print('You have purchased', symbol, 'for', quote)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the recommended iteration for dictionaries in python.

```
stocks = {'GE': 6.28, 'XOM': 39.8}
for key,value in stocks.items():
  print('You have purchased', key, 'for', value)
```